# Why C++ does not perform RVO to std::optional?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, return-value-optimization

I am wondering why C++ does not perform RVO to `std::optional<T>` when returning `T`.
I.e.,

```cpp
struct Bar {};
std::optional<Bar> get_bar()
{
    return Bar{}; // move ctor of Bar called here
                  // instead of performing RVO
}
Bar get_bar2()
{
    return Bar{}; // NO move ctor called
                  // RVO performed
}
std::optional<Bar> get_bar_rvo()
{
    std::optional<Bar> opt;
    opt.emplace();
    return opt;  // NO move ctor called
                 // ROV performed
}
```

In this above case, `get_bar2` performs RVO while `get_bar` does not.

With a little bit more *hint*, the compiler is able to optimize `get_bar_rvo`, but the code get longer and annoying.

From [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), I understand that `get_bar` does not meet the requirement of "Mandatory elision of copy/move operations"

> In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:

Since `std::optional<T>` and `T` are *not* the same class type, so RVO is not mandatory.

However, I *think* that performing RVO to `std::optional<T>` should be very easy and would be very useful, without the need to manually write the longer code as `get_bar_rvo`.
Why my compile fails to recognize and optimize the `get_bar` just like `get_bar2`?

Environments: MacOS

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Compiled with `-std=c++17 -O3`

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the `Bar` object needs to be copied or moved into the `std::optional` data-space.

Comment: Does `return std::optional<Bar>{ Bar{} };` work?

Comment: @RichardCritten or `return { Bar{} };`?

Comment: Manually placing one `std::optional<T> opt` in the function and `return opt` allows RVO. That's an expected behaviour that I want `get_bar` to do.

Comment: `return opt;` is NRVO which is optional.  RVO which is mandatory [Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17) requires a prvalue .

Comment: From my compiler: `return { Bar{} };` does not work.

Comment: Can you try `return std::optional<Bar>{ std::in_place };`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_bar_rvo` does not perform RVO, it performs NRVO (*Named* Return Value Optimization). This is not guaranteed.

For `get_bar`, instead of constructing a `Bar` yourself, you can leave that to `std::optional` using [`std::make_optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional) or [its in-place constructor (6)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional):

```
std::optional<Bar> get_bar()
{
    return std::make_optional<Bar>();
    // or return std::optional<Bar>(std::in_place);
}
```

This performs RVO as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`get_bar()` returns `std::optional<Bar>`, and no `std::optional<Bar>` gets copied or moved, as expected.

`Bar` is moved to `std::optional<Bar>` because you create a temporary `Bar` and then request `std::optional<Bar>` to be constructed from it. It has nothing to do with RVO or NRVO. It is about passing objects to functions.

We do not expect a move to be eliminated in any old function call like `foo(Bar{})`, and `std::optional` constructor is no exception.